# how can i change the runtime libraries (libc ,ld, etc) used by gdb in cross (ARM) debugging

Tags: gdb, runtime, arm

I have an ARM development board based around freescale's iMX6q ARM Cortex A9 processor.
I also have an application that I want to debug on the board.
The dev board is running a running a LTIB filesystem with non stripped runtime libraries.
On the host I have downloaded a Linaro toolchain as well (the soft float 2012.04 to be specific) which has only stripped libraries.

I would like to tell gdb (running on the host) to use a different set of runtime libraries (non stripped ones), from the image of the LTIB filesystem I keep on the host.

How do I do that?

asking gdb to give me

```
(gdb) show debug-file-directory
```

it returns some path that doesn't even exist on my host filesystem....

```
The directory where separate debug symbols are searched for is 
"/cbuild/slaves/oort14/crosstool-ng/builds/arm-linux-gnueabi-linux/install/lib/debug".
```

and I am not even certain this is the right variable to tweak..

update:
even set debug-file-directory doesn't help, the runtime libs used are still in the toolchain path:

```
Reading symbols from /mnt/nfs_host/Linaro/gcc-linaro-arm-linux-gnueabi-2012.04-20120426_linux/arm-linux-gnueabi/libc/lib/ld-linux.so.3...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
```

What could I do? 
Thank you for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use gdb's `set sysroot DIRECTORY` command ([GDB Manual](http://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Files.html#index-set-sysroot-1067)). Suppose you have a copy of the filesystem on the device with debug info at `/LTIB_ROOT`:

```
[device]$ gdbserver --multi :2345
$ arm-linux-gnueabihf-gdb # GDB from Linaro toolchain
(gdb) set sysroot /LTIB_ROOT
(gdb) target extended-remote DEVICE-IP:2345
(gdb) set remote exec-file /bin/true
(gdb) file /LTIB_ROOT/bin/true
(gdb) start
Temporary breakpoint 1 at 0x842c: file XXX.c, line YYY.
(gdb) info sharedlibrary 
From        To          Syms Read   Shared Object Library
0x400007a0  0x4001cf80  Yes         /LTIB_ROOT/lib/ld-linux.so.3
0x40037ea0  0x4004948c  Yes         /LTIB_ROOT/lib/libgcc_s.so.1
0x40068760  0x40172b14  Yes         /LTIB_ROOT/lib/libc.so.6
```

Comment: hi there. Thank you for the command. I am a little fuzzy about the rest of the commands. `set remote exec-file` and `file`. Are they really needed if i am running gdbserver on the target devel board?

Comment: `file` loads the debug info from the main executable, without it `start` wouldn't work as there would be no symbol table at that point. `set remote exec-file` tells gdbserver which file to run and is needed because I started gdbserver in multi process mode.

Comment: In short, `file` is always required. `set remote exec-file` is only required if you run `gdbserver --multi` instead of `gdbserver PROGRAM` but I find the former easier to use as I can just leave gdbserver running.

Comment: Right. I had overlooked that you invoked gdb without arguments, i don't use `file` as I always load `gdb FILE` and it seemed odd. Its clear now though. thanks.