# gdb cannot access variables after spawning a thread

Tags: variables, gdb, pthreads, gdbserver

I am trying to debug an application, after migrating from an old development board to a new one (iMX6 sabre lite  board with ARM cortex A9).
I'm also running gdb on the host and gdbserver on the development board as explain in the __answer__section here [how can i change the runtime libraries (libc ,ld, etc) used by gdb in cross (ARM) debugging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15298377/how-can-i-change-the-runtime-libraries-libc-ld-etc-used-by-gdb-in-cross-arm/15301872?noredirect=1#comment21601674_15301872)

while trying to run the application and on executing the step to create a thread I get this:

```
(gdb) 
681             if (pthread_create(&serial_thread, &attr_detach, read_serial, argv[1]) != 0){
(gdb) 
    Cannot remove breakpoints because program is no longer writable.
    Further execution is probably impossible.
0x00023308 in main (
    argc=<error reading variable: Cannot access memory at address 0x7efffc8c>, 
    argv=<error reading variable: Cannot access memory at address 0x7efffc88>)
    at main_process/main_process.c:681
681             if (pthread_create(&serial_thread, &attr_detach, read_serial, argv[1]) != 0){
    warning: Error removing breakpoint 0
    Cannot access memory at address 0x7efffc88
(gdb) info threads
      Id   Target Id         Frame 
    * 1    Thread 2588.2588  0x00023308 in main (
    argc=<error reading variable: Cannot access memory at address 0x7efffc8c>, 
    argv=<error reading variable: Cannot access memory at address 0x7efffc88>)
    at main_process/main_process.c:681
```

I can not continue with the debug execution after that.
if i simply run through the code (instead of stepping through it) I'll get

```
(gdb) c
Continuing.
[Inferior 1 (process 2601) exited with code 0377]
```

if I add a breakpoint in the thread that is to be created, I will get the execution to halt there, but continuing afterwards is impossible (it will not exit either).

I read about the posibility that the thread stack size may be small, but it is 8MB and I am only passing an argument argv[1] (which is empty at the moment) to the thread.

I used the Linaro gcc-linaro-arm-linux-gnueabi-2012.04-20120426_linux toolchain to create my application. and the shared libraries running on the board (and used while debugging) belong to LTIB_201204 rootfs.

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you first check that `libthread_db.so` exists on the board and that it is unstripped (check `nm` output) ? I've never used LTIB personally but from page 2 this [Freescale application note](http://cache.freescale.com/files/32bit/doc/app_note/AN4553.pdf):

> To correctly catch process events like loading a shared library or
>   creation of a thread, the shared libraries that implement these common
>   functionalities must be deployed on target un-stripped of symbols. For
>   Linux userspace those are ld.so, libthread_db.so, libpthread.so, and
>   for the particular case of i.MX/LTIB, to achieve that uncheck strip
>   options on LTIB Target Image Generation menu.

Comment: hi there. the library does exist in /lib/ and `nm libthread_db-1.0.so` does return quite a few symbols. Also `file libthread_db-1.0.so` returns that the ARM shared lib is not stripped. I had to replace the (preloaded) Timesys linux that came bundled with the board exactly because the shared libs were stripped in there.

Comment: The other thing I think might work is to replace the `lib/` direcotory in LTIB with the one from the toolchain, i.e. copy the contents `gcc-linaro-arm-linux-XXX/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libc/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/` to `/lib` on the board. Also take care to when you `set sysroot` from GDB.

Comment: I am not using the -hf- toolchain, as LTIB is build without it. so I went for another non hardfloat, which is of similar date to the LTIB creation date.I would value your comment on whether I should use the HF toolchain regardles, of the LTIB, but perhaps we should discuss it in another channel. Unfortunately, while the hf toolchain does contain stripped libs, the non hf does not. That's why I ended up asking about the sysroot command in the link provided in the Question.

Comment: unfortunately overwriting the `/lib/` dir on the board with the `gcc-linaro-arm-linux-XXX/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libc/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/` did not yield different results either.. bummer.